# Scaling Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the left ($\mathbf v$) and right ($\mathbf w$) eigenvectors of a matrix and I need to scale them so that the following is true,
$$
\|\mathbf w\|=1 \\[1em]
\mathbf v^\top \mathbf w = 1
$$
The first constraint is easy to compute,
$$
\|\mathbf w\| = 1 = \frac{w_i}{\displaystyle \sum_i w_i}
$$
I'm just not sure how to scale $\mathbf v$, such that $\mathbf v^\top \mathbf w=1$.

Comment: If $v$ and $w$ are perpendicular with each other, you cannot achieve this. Note that eigenvectors of real symmetric matrices are orthogonal. So you need to give a condition for $v$ and $w$.

Comment: Is $\textbf{v}^{\textsf{T}}\textbf{w}$ just $\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{w}$?

Comment: @MPW yes this is what is meant. The point is that all vectors here are column vectors and then $v^Tw$ allows to consider the product as a usual matrix product;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off:  your first rescaling won't work, since
$$
\left\| \frac{w_i}{\displaystyle \sum_i w_i} \right\|^2 = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_i w_i^2}{\left(\displaystyle \sum_i w_i \right)^2} \neq 1.
$$
So check your definitions there.

To rescale $\mathbf{v}$, think about it the following way.  We want a new vector $\tilde{\mathbf{v}}$ which is a multiple of $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\tilde{\mathbf{v}}^T \mathbf{w} = 1$.  Since $\tilde{\mathbf{v}} = \alpha \mathbf{v}$ for some $\alpha$, this implies that
$$
1 = \tilde{\mathbf{v}}^T \mathbf{w} = \alpha \left( {\mathbf{v}}^T \mathbf{w} \right)
$$
and so
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{{\mathbf{v}}^T \mathbf{w}} = \left( \sum_i v_i w_i \right)^{-1}.
$$

Note that this will not be possible if the original $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are orthogonal (i.e., if ${\mathbf{v}}^T \mathbf{w} = 0$).  Note also that nothing in this construction relies on the fact that $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are eigenvectors of a matrix.

Comment: Thanks @michael-seifert!  That was really easy, I should of thought about it a bit more.  I may of botched the notation, by $||\mathbf w||$  I simply wanted to state that $\mathbf w$ was scaled so that it summed to unity.

Comment: Ah, you're using a different norm than I was expecting ($\| \mathbf{w} \| = \sum w_i$, not $\| \mathbf{w} \| = \sqrt{\sum w_i^2}$.)  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you scale $\textbf v$ by $a$ and $\textbf w$ by $b$. You want $||b\textbf w||=1$ and $(a\textbf v)\cdot(b\textbf w)=1$.

$1 = ||b\textbf{w}|| = |b|\;||\textbf w||$ so you can take $$\boxed{b=1/||\textbf w||}$$ (provided $\textbf w \neq \textbf 0$).

$1 = (a\textbf v)\cdot(b\textbf w)= (a/||\textbf w||)(\textbf v\cdot \textbf w)$ so you can take $$\boxed{a =  ||\textbf w|| / (\textbf v\cdot \textbf w)}$$ (provided $\textbf v\cdot \textbf w \neq \textbf 0$).

Note that the caveats are $\textbf w \neq \textbf 0$ and $\textbf v\cdot \textbf w \neq \textbf 0$.